# Annotation-based usage of jamon in spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, jamon

To use [`jamon`](http://jamonapi.com/) in [`spring`](http://spring.io/), it's [described](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/spring_aop_monitoring.html) to use `JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor` and put it to springs AOP-mechanism via a `applicationContext.xml`. It's explained, and there's an example within the [tests in it's sources](http://sourceforge.net/p/jamonapi/jamonapi/ci/master/tree/jamon/src/test/java/com/jamonapi/aop/spring/JamonAspectTest.java). Unfortunately, I want to build a spring-boot application without any xml-configuration.
Is it possible to use some annotations to include the `JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor` to spring?

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never...

I had the very same situation: I needed to configure JAMon without any XML configuration. Most of the examples online (including the comments in the JAMon source code) advertise XML configuration flexibility, but I couldn't find any examples with annotation based configuration. Also annotation-based configs are not necessarily less flexible, they just need to be conceptually separated and not confused with functional parts of the application. I think such advisor can be a good example:

```
@Component
public class MonitoringAdvisor extends AbstractPointcutAdvisor {

    private final StaticMethodMatcherPointcut pointcut = new StaticMethodMatcherPointcut() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
                return targetClass.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class);
            }
        };

    @Override
    public Pointcut getPointcut() {
        return this.pointcut;
    }

    @Override
    public Advice getAdvice() {
        return new JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor(true, true);
    }
}
```

This advisor would let Spring/AOP know to run JAMon monitoring advice on any method of Spring bean annotated with `@RestContrller`. This advisor should be configured/added to the same Spring context as rest controllers.

Note, that in my case I specifically wanted to monitor my rest controllers. One can adapt the advisor according to his/her own needs. (In my code I use a more advanced/configurable version of the presented advisor)

Answer (score 0):

Is this [Spring Boot sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-aop) helpful?

Here is the relevant part of the [Spring AOP manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj).